# How to stop service communication using namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I only start to use kubernetes recently. Let us say there are two service: `service-a` and `service-b` in the same cluster and same namespace `dev`.

Usually `service-a` to call `service-b`, I will use `http://service-b:3000`, however, today I discovered that I can also call `service-b` using `http://service-b.dev:3000`, how can I stop this behavior and only allow the service communication without namespace, i.e. `http://service-b:3000`?

Comment: The fully-qualified name should generally be something like `service-b.dev.svc.cluster.local`.  Why do you want to forbid using longer parts of the DNS name?  How is your application code affected by this?

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes that is what I read and understand as well. the full name is service-b.dev.svc.cluster.local, but apparently even service-b.dev is also working. I want to stop this because I am devops for the team, and we have a guideline to only allow http://service-b:3000 to have a same coding standard